# Disable one input field based on second input field entery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 Input text fields, When user trying to enter any value in A input text field then B input field need to disable not be allowed to any entry in B field. same way if user tryid to enter any input in B input field then A input field need to disable.
Can anyone help me how write code in Jquery

Answer (score 3):

With the input field names of `A` and `B`.

```
$('input[name="A"]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() !== ''){
        $('input[name="B"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }else{
        $('input[name="B"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
$('input[name="B"]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() !== ''){
        $('input[name="A"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }else{
        $('input[name="A"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: `removeattr()` should be `removeAttr()`. It wont work without the camel case.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers are correct, just decided to make the code short:

```
    $('input.inputA').keyup(function () {
        $('input.inputB').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
    });

    $('input.inputB').keyup(function () {
        $('input.inputA').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AnDxC/

Answer (score 2):

assuming

```
<input type="text" class="inputA" />
<input type="text" class="inputB" />
```

and JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").on("keyup", function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("inputA") && $(".inputA").val()){
               $("input.inputB").prop("disabled", true);
               $("input.inputA").prop("disabled", false);
            } else if($(this).hasClass("inputB") && $(".inputB").val()){
               $("input.inputA").prop("disabled", true);
                $("input.inputB").prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                       $(".inputA, .inputB").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHVhh/1/)

Comment: `$('.inputA').val()` will return truey and falsey so there is no need for ">0", unless that's some kind of performance thing.

Comment: You've missed the case when both fields are empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the next HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" value=""/>
```

my solution is:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#test1, #test2').keyup(function(){
        var $test1 = $('#test1');
        var $test2 = $('#test2');
        $test1.prop('disabled', $test2.val() && ! $test1.val());
        $test2.prop('disabled', $test1.val() && ! $test2.val());
    });
});
</script>
```

here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/94a5b/)